# NTP / SNTP and UTC Time

Tags: ntp, time-synchronization

I'm trying to get a little bit smarter about the NTP & SNTP protocols.  I have read through the RFC's and understand how the protocol works, but I'm uncertain about the timestamps themselves.  The RFC's don't actually state that all timestamps are normalized to UTC time, but it seems that they must be.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the NTP servers all talk UTC and your local machine translates that into whatever time is appropriate based on your timezone settings.